# Scanner example loop

Tags: java, loops, methods, integration, java.util.scanner

Values are entered until a 0 is entered. Then the program ends, but before that happens the sum of all values are given if they were Integral numbers.

This is what I have tried so far but I'm stuck.

```
public class Aufgabe2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* TODO: add code here */
        int n;
        int sum = 0;
        boolean exit = true;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



        while (true) {

            n = input.nextInt();

            if (n == 0) {
                exit = true;
            } else {
                sum += n;
                System.out.println(sum);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some good doco on Scanner on the oracle website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Scanner will throw an error in the event that the token you are expecting is not there.  I would recommend you check for an integer `input.hasNextInt()` before you attempt to parse it.

Something like this:

```
int sum = 0;
boolean exit = true;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (input.hasNextInt()) {

  int n = input.nextInt();

  if (n == 0) {
    break;
  } else {
    sum += n;
  }
}
// Print outside of the loop
System.out.println(sum);
```

Result of the program

```
Input:
  1
  2
  3
  0
Output:
  6
```

Comment: OOPS. By mistake, I have edited your answer instead of mine. sorry.

Comment: No worries, I've fixed it up

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
int n;
int sum = 0;
boolean exit = true;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (exit) {
    n = input.nextInt();

    if (n == 0) {
        exit = false;
    }
    else {
        sum += n;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

You have a `while(true)` which is a continuous loop.

Comment: and it gives nothing..should it be like that?

Comment: you have to provide the inputs, NO? you are using Scanner to read inputs from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Aufgabe2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* TODO: add code here */
        int n;
        int sum = 0;
        boolean exit = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!exit) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number:");
            n = input.nextInt();
            if (n == 0) {
                exit = true;
            } else {
                sum += n;
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number:
1
1
Enter a number:
3
4
Enter a number:
6
10
Enter a number:
0
```

Edit:

You have to change `while (true)` loop to use boolean variable `exit`. I have modified the code accordingly and corrected the `while` loop condition.

Comment: Giving him code without explaining why it works doesn't help him at all.

Comment: Done. I have answered the question long time back when I am not aware of working style of website. But as long as this answer is useful to OP, I am happy irrespective of up vote or down vote.